# Правильное взаимодействие компонентов в MVC и синхронизация корзины

Tags: база-данных, mvc, cms, сессия, cleancode

Всем здравствуйте.
Пишу кастомную cms. Корзина обрабатывается двумя разными моделями в зависимости от того залогинен пользователь или нет: если залогинен, то корзина пишется в БД, если не залогинен то в сессии. При логировании пользователя необходимо перевести корзину из сессии в БД. Я написал для этого отдельный класс, инициализация и вызов методов которого вызывается из ЮзерКонтроллера (при логировании). Вопрос такой: если написанный мною класс синхронизации корзин является моделью, то может ли он вызывать методы моделей БдКорзины и СессииКорзины? Насколько я знаю это противоречит базовой концепции MVC, а хочется сделать все более менее аккуратно и правильно. Думал написать отдельный класс, и не модель и не контроллер, но как-то мне кажется тоже неправильно.
Проконсультируйте, пожалуйста, предложите варианты решения, которые мне пока не видны, из-за малого количества опыта.

Comment: если вам так не нравится, при логировании юзера вы же должны как-то инициализировать корзину, вот и запросите корзину из модели локальной корзины и отдайте на инициализацию бдкорзины

Comment: А такой вариант не противоречит solidу? Принцип единственной ответственности класса ЮзерКонтроллер делает логирование, регистрацию и логаут, а Синхронизатор делает синхронизацию корзин. Так нарушается абстракция ЮзерКонтроллера

Comment: я думаю, что что-то всегда нарушается. Но механизм инициализации корзины что-то типа user->basket = new Basket() у вас в контроллере написано. Или делайте фабрику для корзин, она и разберется, или тут проверьте, есть ли локальная и отдайте   user->basket = new Basket(local_cart). Разница в корзинах в основном про сохранение, а все остальное - одинаковое

Comment: Логика выбора модели для записи корзины у меня есть и все плюс минус как вы и описали, обошелся без фабрики, просто метод в АппКонтроллере от которого наследуются все остальные контроллеры. Хотя с фабрикой отличная идея, я её рассмотрю, спасибо. Но вопрос то остается открытым: как написать синхронизатор не нарушив солид и мвс? Я понимаю что это уже наверно архитектурное решение и я накосячил при проектировании "на коленке", но снова же, это все от маленького опыта.

Comment: подождем гуру. я на строгое следование всегда, честно говоря, забивал. Но у меня опыт тоже не сильно большой

Comment: Гуру так и не снизошел до нас, простых смертных. Буду делать как посоветовал дорогой splash58. Все-таки сделанное лучше идеального.

Comment: *Все-таки сделанное лучше идеального* - одобряю :)